# javascript object handling

Tags: javascript

this is my question, how can i delete properties that doesn't exist in the first.

1st object

```
object1= [1,2,3];
```

2st object

```
object2 = [4];

if (!(object1 in object2) delete object2
```

Comment: @Shlomi: I've rolled back your edit. You've assumed you know what the question is. We can all have our theories, but it's up to @Tarun to actually edit the question and say what he/she is asking.

Comment: Someone was kind enough to fix the code formatting for you, and you un-fixed it. Please take a moment to read the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the Ask a Question area, and [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. (There's also a preview box shown under the Ask a Question box where you can preview your question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming :

```
var obj1={prop1:1,prop2:2...};
var obj2={prop1:2,prop3:"x"...};
```

You can try :

```
for (prop in obj2) {
    if (!(prop in obj1)) delete obj2[prop];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give that a go

```
var flag = false;
var max = object1.length;
var max2 = object2.length;
for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < max2; j++) {
         if (object1[i] == object2[j])
         {
            object2.splice(j,1);
            max2 = max2 -1;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and loop through the second array to see if they exist.